# How to get tails of sequence clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

I have sequence in clojure of theem

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

how can I get all the tails of sequence like

```
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another  way to get all tails is by using the [`reductions`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reductions) function.

```
user=> (def x '(1 2 3 4))
#'user/x
user=> (reductions (fn [s _] (rest s)) x x)
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ())
user=>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this with higher-level functions, I think `iterate` would work well here:

```
(defn tails [xs]
  (concat (take-while seq (iterate rest xs)) '(()))
```

However, I think in this case it would be cleaner to just write it with `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn tails [xs]
  (if-not (seq xs) '(())
    (cons xs (lazy-seq (tails (rest xs))))))
```

Comment: Thanks this results in ([1 2 3 4] (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ()) why the first one is in vector form?

Comment: @hariszaman that's because iterate returns first the second argument itself without applying the function. Then it starts applying `rest` which returns a `ChunkedSeq` which prints the same way as list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
user=> (def x [1 2 3 4])
#'user/x
user=> (map #(drop % x) (range (inc (count x))))
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ())
```

Comment: this should not be used on lazy sequences, the call to count forces the entire sequence

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is by

```
(defn tails [coll]
  (take (inc (count coll)) (iterate rest coll)))
```

Comment: this will force any lazy input

Comment: Yes, due to count. I didn't really think about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn tails
  [s]
  (cons s (if-some [r (next s)]
            (lazy-seq (tails r))
            '(()))))
```

Comment: Oh. Heh. I guess my REPL is running 1.5.

Comment: How could you reply within 15sec?

Comment: I was just about to close my SO window when you commented. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yippee! Another one:

```
(defn tails [coll]
    (if-let [s (seq coll)]
        (cons coll (lazy-seq (tails (rest coll))))
        '(())))
```

This is really just what `reductions` does under the hood. The best answer, by the way, is [ez121sl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267216/2472391).